# Cronjob com arquivo em cache

Tags: php, cache

No meu site e usando o cpanel, tenho vários cronjobs que executam vários arquivos php.
Cada um desses cronjobs, cria um arquivo em cache onde o site vai pegar informação.
Todos os cronjobs estão funcionando bem, mas eu estou tendo um problema com um deles.
Este cronjob que eu estou falando, leva cerca de 1,5 minutos para atualizar o arquivo em cache porque vai pegar valores de várias fontes e esse processo é demorado. 
Faz tudo em conformidade e a actualização é perfeita, mas ...

O problema é que o arquivo em cache é excluído assim que se inicia o cronjob e o novo aquivo de cache só irá aparecer depois que todos os valores foram coletados (1,5 minutos depois).
Assim sendo, se um usuário do site, tiver o azar de consultar a página que depende desse cache durante o processo de atualização, vai acabar desistindo por achar que não está funcionando.

Tenho tentado soluções mas sem êxito.

A solução que me parece a melhor, seria esta:
- o arquivo em cache permanece em uso enquanto está sendo criado um novo cache por meio de um arquivo temporário.
- quando este arquivo temporário estiver concluído com todos os novos valores já atualizados, só então ele substitui o arquivo em cache atual.

Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como conseguir isto?

Comment: me parece que é apenas problema de fluxo mesmo. Se você não puder considerar outra técnica de cache (caso o seu sistema seja, de fato, dependente desse meio de cache), a melhor solução é a que você mesmo citou: faz-se a substituição do arquivo de cache apenas quando a task do cron estiver sido concluída. Se o cache que você usa é simples (apenas de HTML), considere usar ferramentas como [PHP OP Cache](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.opcache.php). Se seu site for em WordPress o [WPSuperCache](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) pode ser uma boa solução.

Comment: Por nada. Coloquei o comentário como resposta, já que te ajudou.

Answer (score 2):

Modifique os processos de agendamento para que, enquanto busca novas informações, ao invés de apagar o cache corrente, gere os novos dados num novo arquivo. Assim que completar esse novo arquivo renomeie-o com o nome do arquivo principal, o qual será substituído.

1. Arquivo do cache principal: "dados.txt"

2. O cron executa os processos e salva em "dados-novos.txt"

3. Quando completar os dados novos: renomeia "dados-novos.txt" para "dados.txt".

Não quer dizer que esse seja o único ou o melhor modo de resolver. Dependendo de como é a estrutura dos dados, os processos, etc, pode existir outros meios mas como isso não é claro na pergunta, essa é uma opção mais óbvia.

Comment: Essa técnica serve para tudo praticamente, para FTP (quando for atualizar os arquivos renome depois que já está no servidor), para banco de dados (quando tiver que dar drop uma tabela muito grande, crie uma com a mesma estrutura renomeia e deleta).

Comment: Simples e eficaz. +1

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que é apenas problema de fluxo mesmo. Se você não puder considerar outra técnica de cache (caso o seu sistema seja, de fato, dependente desse meio de cache), a melhor solução é a que você mesmo citou: faz-se a substituição do arquivo de cache apenas quando a task do cron estiver sido concluída. Se o cache que você usa é simples (apenas de HTML), considere usar ferramentas como [PHP OP Cache](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.opcache.php). Se seu site for em WordPress o [WPSuperCache](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) pode ser uma boa solução.